# file_get_contents or read JSON file from Controller

Tags: php, json, fat-free-framework

I am getting started with the F3 Framework (Fat Free Framework) and so far it's great. Simple and light. I set it up so that my controllers are in a separate folder App/Controllers and that is working great using classes and namespaces. On thing I'm having trouble with is reading a JSON file from one of those controllers. My code is below:

```
$json = $f3->read('settings/templates.json');
$templates = json_decode($json);
var_dump($templates);
$fields = $templates->$template->fields;
```

I tried it like that and like this

```
$json = file_get_contents('settings/templates.json');
$templates = json_decode($json);
var_dump($templates);
$fields = $templates->$template->fields;
```

But either way I get a file not found error. So somehow, F3 is not finding the file. I'm not sure if I need to include this in the AUTOLOAD or if there is some better way to do this.

I tried it as a database like so and it finds the file, but somehow this doesn't seem right:

```
$db = new \DB\Jig ( 'settings/' , \DB\Jig::FORMAT_JSON );
$user= new \DB\Jig\Mapper($db, 'templates.json');
var_dump($templates);
$fields = $templates->$template->fields;
```

It seems like I shouldn't be using the DB class and Jig just to read a simple JSON file. Can someone please shed some light on this?

EDIT: Ok the answer below helped, but in my particular case, everything (the syntax) was right. I think the reason it didn't work was because I had the paths wrong in this line of my index.php

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','App/Controllers/');
```

Comment: If you are getting a file not found error, the problem is not with your logic.  Try using an absolute path for the file using the `__DIR__` constant.  this constant will return the path of the directory of the php file that is calling it.  I'm not sure where your settings dir is, but something like this could help: `__DIR__ . '../settings/templates.json'`

Comment: Ok yeah that works, but I can't help feeling that it's not the "right" way per the F3 documentation....

Comment: The `$f3->read('settings/templates.json')` should work, provided 1) the `settings/` folder is located aside `index.php` 2) you didn't change the working directory via `cd`. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case. I'll give it a try

Comment: yes that worked! answer it and I'll accept it @xfra35

Comment: Ok I've posted an answer to detail the concept of relative paths. By the way, the command to change the working directory in PHP is `chdir`, not `cd` (as I've mistakenly written above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is not related to the framework but to your understanding of relatives paths in PHP. Relative paths are always relative to the [working directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

If you're using the framework for the web (and not in CLI mode), the working directory is the directory where your `index.php` is located, as long as you don't explicitly change the working directory with the [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) command.

You can verify it by echoing `getcwd()` at the very top of your script.

That means that any relative path used in your application (no matter if it's being called from `index.php`, `lib/web.php`, `app/controllers/foo.php` or any file located in any directory) is relative to that directory.

So in your case, the `settings` directory is expected to be found in the same directory as `index.php`:

```
apps/
  controllers/
settings/
  templates.json
index.php
```

Comment: I understand relative paths. I think in my case I had double quotes but actually needed single quotes. Either way, you helped. Thanks!

Comment: The `getcwd()` saved me :D